# T-sql query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a Query Like That

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    b.ID,
    a.Wallet,
    b.Total
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN b ON b.IID= a.ID
WHERE
    b.ID= 19
AND b.IsActive = 1
```

I get this result

```
a.ID      b.ID     Wallet      Total
1         19        1000        250
1         19        1000        500
```

When i run this query

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN b ON b.IID= a.ID
SET a.Wallet= a.Wallet+ b.Total
WHERE
    b.ID= 19
AND b.IsActive = 1
```

My b table wallet value updated from 1000 to 1250 but the true result going to be b table wallet value from 1000 to 1750 where is my fail ?

> ****** EDİT ******

Table Schemas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wallets` (
  `wallet_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wallet` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wallet_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `wallets` (`wallet_id`, `wallet`) VALUES
  ('1', '100'),
  ('2', '100');

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `totals` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `TotalID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wallet_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `total` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `totals` (`id`, `TotalID`,`wallet_id`,`total`) VALUES
  ('1', '19','1', '250'),
 ('2', '19','1', '750');
```

UPDATE QUERY

```
UPDATE wallets inner join totals on totals.wallet_id=wallets.wallet_id
SET 
wallets.wallet=wallets.wallet+totals.total
Where totals.TotalID=19
```

SELECT QUERY

```
SELECT * from wallets inner join totals on totals.wallet_id=wallets.wallet_id
```

Comment: Surprised this even returns records. You do `a.ID=b.ID` and your IDs are different..

Comment: How do you get different IDs back?

Comment: @barrick I edited this query

Comment: Please add `DDL` for your table's with example data and expected result, as it is still not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  a
SET     wallet = wallet + b_sum
FROM    a
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  SUM(total) AS b_sum
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.iid = a.id
                AND b.id = 19
                AND b.isActive = 1
        ) b
```

Comment: Noo it's going to update all a table wallet value. It's not safely.

Comment: This is actually wrong considering OP's updated query. They don't use `a`'s columns for the WHERE, and `a.id` is equated with `b.iid` not `b.id`.

Comment: The where clause means it will only update rows with `a.id =19`

Comment: @Vasan: the where says b.id must be 19, and the inner join condition means a.id must be 19 too

Comment: @Andomar Nope, again: if you look more carefully, the inner join condition is not against b.id. It's against b.iid (i.e. b.id is different from b.iid). It wouldn't be logical to compare against b.id and get back this data.

Comment: I Updated again the query. Check now sir. Its cleanly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE a
  SET a.Wallet= a.Wallet+ tmp.Total    
FROM a 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Total) as Total
             FROM b 
             WHERE b.Id = a.Id 
             AND   b.ID= 19
             AND b.IsActive = 1
             ) tmp
```

Comment: Right, the cross join will act as a filter +1

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use SUM (b.Total) with a GROUP BY b.ID to get that value to match up. Right now your update query is just matching up the first ID it finds.

Comment: You could probably do without it, actually. Just make sure you don't try to do that in its present form with more than one b.ID at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope its working fine**

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Wallet = a.Wallet+f.valsum
FROM 
(
  SELECT  b.IID,SUM(b.Total) valsum
  FROM b
  WHERE b.IsActive = 1 AND b.ID= 19
  GROUP BY  b.IID
) f
WHERE ON a.ID = f.IID;
```